# El indice estaba fuera del intervalo Crystal Report

Tags: c#, windows-forms, crystal-reports, reportviewer, dataset

Tengo otro pequeño gran dilema con estos sub reportes , estoy tratando de enviar datos a dos diferentes subreportes en el primero funciona sin problema alguno, el dilema consiste cuando añado el segundo reporte y se produce la excepción motivo por el cual es el titulo de la pregunta.

El error que muestro a continuación es inmediatamente después de realizar el envió los datos al segundo sub reporte y se produce la excepcion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 private void FormReporteAdmMensual_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        try
        {
            String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                try
                {
                    ConnectionInfo myConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                    myConnectionInfo.ServerName = "SISTEMAS-PC";
                    myConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "SISROL";
                    myConnectionInfo.UserID = "TECNOLOGIA";
                    myConnectionInfo.Password = "tecnologia";
                    myConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                    String filePath = @"Z:\Sisrol-Net\Reportes\ReporteMensualAdm3Meses.rpt";                        
                    //String filePath = @"Z:\Sisrol-Net\Reportes\ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt";
                    //Cargar el Reporte
                    rd.Load(filePath);                       
                    //Asignarle al Reporte el DataSet                    
                    rd.Subreports[0].SetDataSource(RolAdm3Mes(fechin, fechin.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1), "0930159520"));
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAI", fechin, "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAF", fechin.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1), "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@CEDULA", "0930159520", "ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt");

                    DateTime TmpSubReport1 = fechin.AddMonths(1);
                    DateTime TmpSubReport2 = fechin.AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1);

                    rd.Subreports[1].SetDataSource(RolAdm3Mes2(TmpSubReport1, TmpSubReport2, "0930159520")); --> AQUÍ GENERA LA EXCEPCIÓN
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAI2", TmpSubReport1, "ReporteRolAdminHisMes2.rpt");
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@FECHAF2", TmpSubReport2, "ReporteRolAdminHisMes2.rpt");
                    rd.SetParameterValue("@CEDULA2", "0930159520", "ReporteRolAdminHisMes2.rpt");

                    //Asignarle al CrystalReportViewer el ReportDocument                         
                    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
                    SetDBLogonForReport(myConnectionInfo); 

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR REPORT: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

El reporte principal ReporteMensualAdm3Meses.rpt como se ve en la imagen que adjunto consta de sub reporte ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt el cual si se coloca de manera unitaria funciona y el segundo sub reporte ReporteRolAdminHisMes2.rpt que es cuando lo ejecuto me da la excepción visualizada en la imagen anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación el código de RolAdm3Mes y RolAdm3Mes2 que se ejecuta para llenar cada uno de los DataSet para el correspondiente informe.

```
public static SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula RolAdm3Mes(DateTime fecini, DateTime fecfin, String Cedula)
    {

        SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula ds = new SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RolMensualAdmCedula", cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@FECHAI", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fecini.ToShortDateString();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI", fecini.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF", fecfin.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEDULA", Cedula);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds,"RolMensualAdmCedula");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return ds;
    }

    public static SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula2 RolAdm3Mes2(DateTime fecini, DateTime fecfin, String Cedula)
    {

        SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula2 ds = new SISROLDataSetRolMensualAdmCedula2();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString()))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("RolMensualAdmCedula2", cnn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                    
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAI2", fecini.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHAF2", fecfin.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CEDULA2", Cedula);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(ds, "RolMensualAdmCedula2");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

Que estaría realizando de manera errónea :(

Comment: Tienes dos subinformes en el informe principal? o quieres mostrar los datos de dos consultas en el mismo informe-subinforme? segun tu codigo al informe principal le has añadido dos subinformes.

Comment: El informe principal es ReporteMensualAdm3Meses.rpt y dentro de ese tengo 2 sub informe ReporteRolAdminHis.rpt y ReporteRolAdminHisMes2.rpt , el problema viene cuando añado el segundo y me genera ese error descrito en la imagen.

Comment: Has comprobado cuantos elementos hay en  rd.Subreports? puedes poner MessageBox.Show( rd.Subreports.Count) a ver que sale

Comment: Realizando tu sugerencia lo coloco antes de que se genere la excepcion y me arroja solo 1

Comment: Puedes poner una foto del informe principal donde agregas los dos subinformes? es que solo hay un subinforme

Comment: Adjunte una foto de como esta conformado mi reporte

Comment: Puedes mover los subinformes de seccion? y poner por ejemplo uno en el encabezado del informe y el otro en el pie y pruebas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106716/discussion-between-carrobe90-and-juanjo).